# Pandas: get the cumulative sum of a column only if the timestamp is greater than that of another column

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

For each customer, I would like to get the cumulative sum of a column (Dollar Value) only when Timestamp 1 is less than Timestamp 2. I could do a cartesian join of the values based on Customer or iterate through the dataframe, but wanted to see if there was an easier way to to do this maybe with a groupby and apply.

DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['Alice','Brian','Alice','Alice','Alice','Brian', 'Brian'], 'Timestamp': [1,2,3,4,5,3,6], 'Timestamp 2': [2,5,4,6,7,5,7], 'Dollar Value':[0,1,3,5,3,2,3]})
```

Sort Values:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Customer','Timestamp'])
```

Expected Results:

```
df['Desired_result'] = [0,0,0,3,0,0,3]
```

[image: DataFrame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work

get the rows where the condition match and then do cumsum

```py
cond = df["Timestamp"]>df["Timestamp 2"]
df["Dollar Value"].where(cond, 0).groupby([cond, df["Customer"]]).cumsum()
```

**Edit**
based on you comment may be this is what you want

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['Alice','Brian','Alice','Alice','Alice','Brian', 'Brian'], 'Timestamp': [1,2,3,4,5,3,6], 'Timestamp 2': [2,5,4,6,7,5,7], 'Dollar Value':[0,1,3,5,3,2,3]})

def sum_dollar_value(group):
    group = group.copy()
    last_row = group.iloc[-1, :]
    cond = group["Timestamp 2"]<last_row["Timestamp"]
    group.loc[last_row.name, "result"] = np.sum(group["Dollar Value"].where(cond, 0))
    return group

df.groupby("Customer").apply(sum_dollar_value).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But it wouldn't take into consideration the customer... I would like to also group by customer

Comment: you can also add customer in groupby, I have edited the answer

Comment: This will compare the timestamps for each row, but what I'm looking for is for *each customer*, the sum of the 'Dollar Value' column for ALL of the cases where timestamp 2 is less than timestamp 1. Refer to "Desired_result" column. The fourth "Alice" value is 3 because only 2 and 4 (Timestamp 2) are less than 5 (Timestamp 1)

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest setting a condition, then grouping by customer:**

```
# set condition
cond = df["Timestamp"]<df["Timestamp 2"]
df[cond].groupby('Customer')['Dollar Value'].sum()
```

> *Note: I borrowed the syntax of condition from the previous answer by [Dev Khadka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58151642/10521959)*